# How to add ts(Transport Stream) on web.xml(Server) as a MIME TYPE

Tags: tomcat, mime-types, web.xml, mp4, transport-stream

I am using Spring mvc project and Tomcat 7.0.

In some reason, I want add new MIME TYPE to my web.xml.

new MIME TYPE is .ts(Transport stream file, not TypeScript).

So the idea was duplicate every MIME setting for mp4, and replace "mp4" to "ts".

But in "web.xml", there are too many things related with mp4.

So I really frustrated:(

I hope you teach me how to add Transport Stream file to web.xml.

I thank in advanced:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it by myself:D

original MIME TYPE of ts(Transport Stream) is mp2t.

So if you want to add this to your web.xml(in Server),

you can write like below.

```
 <mime-mapping>
     <extension>ts</extension>
     <mime-type>video/mp2t</mime-type>
 </mime-mapping>
```

but even though you finished set up,

almost browser(except Picture Motion Browser) can not

play this format. So if you got any idea, please share~

Comment: It is both answer, and a new question. Pls ask new question.
Also, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @Michael I want to close it myself, but I do not know how. So I am going to choose my answer by myself. But there is time limit. I can choose it at least tomorrow. Sorry^^;;